# Print output of "time" shell command without losing formatting

Tags: python, bash, time

For some reason, when I run "time ./" from the terminal, I get this format:

```
real	0m0.090s
user	0m0.086s
sys	0m0.004s
```

But when I execute the same command in Python 2.7.6:

```
result = subprocess.Popen("time ./<binary>", shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

...I get this format when I `print(result.stderr)`:

```
0.09user 0.00system 0:00.09elapsed
```

Is there any way I can force the **first** (real, user, sys) format?

Comment: How are you displaying / `print`ing `result`?  Or is that just what's appearing on your console or in some IDE's "output" window?

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase just by a simple print.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  On my Python 3.1 (all I've got handy), `Popen` doesn't have a custom `__str__` method, so `print(result)` just displays `<subprocess.Popen object at 0x2068fd0>`.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase I'm using Python 2.7.6. By the way I'm not printing "result", I'm printing "stderr" (consider Martjin's code as the updated version). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `man time` documentation:

> After the utility finishes, time writes the total time elapsed, the time consumed by system overhead, and the time used to execute utility **to the standard error stream.**

Bold emphasis mine. You are capturing the *stdout* stream, not the `stderr` stream, so whatever output you *see* must be the result of something else mangling your Python stderr stream.

Capture `stderr`:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("time ./<binary>", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```

The `stderr` variable then holds the `time` command output.

If this continues to produce the same output, your `/bin/bash` implementation has a built-in `time` command that overrides the `/usr/bin/time` version (which probably outputs everything on one line). You can force the use of the bash builtin by telling Python to run with that:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("time ./<binary>", shell=True, executable='/bin/bash',
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```

Comment: Also [the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) says to pass `-p` in POSIX mode for precise/portable output.

Comment: @PeterWood Yes, but POSIX mode lacks precision compared to the format I'm after.

Comment: @PeterWood: `-p` outputs without tabs and in floating point format.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I still get the same format though. ("0.08user 0.00system 0:00.08elapsed")

Comment: @Xpl0: wait, so now you get that via the captured `stderr`? I can't reproduce this; I get newlines and non-POSIX output. What OS? What is the output of `print(repr(stderr))`? I tested on OS X and Debian Linux.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The output of that is my binary's prints plus the time, just like this ("0.08user 0.00system 0:00.08elapsed"). I've done exactly what you suggested; weird! Running on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Same thing happens with the simple command "time ls". When executed through the terminal, I get newlines and non-POSIX output, but I get 
"0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed" doing what we are discussing.

Comment: @Xpl0: strange; because even the `time -p` output includes *newlines*, which is why I ask for `repr(stderr)` output here. Try running `/bin/sh`, (opens a new shell), then run `time ls`. Exiting that shell brings you back to your regular shell. If that shows the same change, can you tell me what `which time` is producing in regular and sub-shell?

Comment: @MartijnPieters after I opened a new shell, "time ls" displayed like this (0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed). When I exited that shell and tried the same command, it displayed with newlines and non-POSIX. Now, both in the shell and out of it, "which time" produced the same: /usr/bin/time. Any thoughts? Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Xpl0: one of those shells appears to have a built-in version; try with `subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'time ./<binary>', shell=False, ...)` (so use a different shell to run the command).

Comment: @Xpl0: I just tried `/usr/bin/time ls` and reproduced the output you see (with a little more whitespace), so it is your main shell that overrides this with a builtin with more power.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This finally gives me newlines and non-POSIX output, BUT any binary I run seems to not execute or something because I get zero times (and execution in over instantly).

Comment: @Xpl0: I updated the `/bin/bash` option slightly, using the `executable` argument.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's working now with your update! Thank you for all the time (no pun intended) you took to help me. Cheers!

Comment: I assumed the use of `shell=True` meant @Xpl0 _wanted_ the built-in version of `time`.  (Yes, it _usually_ means "I couldn't be bothered to separate my arguments into individual strings" or "I haven't been burned by `shell=True` yet", but _this_ time...)

Answer (score 3):

First: [Martijn Pieters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635424/4116239) is correct about needing to capture `time`'s `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

Also, at least on older versions of Python like 3.1, a [`subprocess.Popen` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) contains several things that could be considered "output".  Attempting to `print` one just results in:

```
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x2068fd0>
```

If later versions are `print`-able, they must do some processing of their contents, probably including mangling the output.

## Reading (and Printing) from `Popen` Object

The `Popen` object has a [`stderr` field](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stderr), which is a readable, file-like object.  You *can* `read` from it like any other file-like object, although it's not recommended.  Quoting the big, pink [security warning](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill):

> ### Warning
>
> Use [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) rather than [`.stdin.write`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin), [`.stdout.read`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout) or [`.stderr.read`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stderr) to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

To print your `Popen`'s contents, you must:

1. [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) with the sub-process, assigning the 2-tuple it returns (`stdout`, `stderr`) to local variable(s).
2. Convert the variable's contents into strings --- by default, it's a `bytes` object, as if the "file" had been opened in *binary* mode.

Below is a tiny program that prints the `stderr` output of a shell command *without* mangling (not counting the conversion from ASCII to Unicode and back).

```python3
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

def main():
    result = subprocess.Popen(
      'time sleep 0.2',
      shell=True,
      stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
      )
    stderr = result.communicate()[1]
    stderr_text = stderr.decode('us-ascii').rstrip('\n')
    #print(stderr_text)  # Prints all lines at once.

    # Or, if you want to process output line-by-line...
    lines = stderr_text.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
    return

if "__main__" == __name__:
    main()
```

This output is on an old Fedora Linux system, running `bash` with `LC_ALL` set to `"C"`:

```
real	0m0.201s
user	0m0.000s
sys	0m0.001s
```

Note that you'll want to add some error-handling around my script's `stderr_text = stderr.decode(...)` line...  For all I know, `time` emits non-ASCII characters depending on localization, environment variables, etc.

## Alternative: `universal_newlines`

You can save some of the decoding boilerplate by using the [`universal_newlines` option to `Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#index-1).  It does the conversion from `bytes` to `strings` automatically:

> If *universal_newlines* is `True`, these file objects will be opened as text streams in [universal newlines](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) mode using the encoding returned by [`locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding).  [...]

```python3
def main_universal_newlines():
    result = subprocess.Popen(
      'time sleep 0.2',
      shell=True,
      stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
      universal_newlines=True,
      )
    stderr_text = result.communicate()[1].rstrip('\n')
    lines = stderr_text.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
    return
```

Note that I still have to strip the last `'\n'` manually to exactly match the shell's output.

Comment: @Xpl0:  I've replaced my original answer with an alternative that uses the (safer) `communicate` method.  Also, I've suggested using `universal_newlines` to avoid having to explicitly convert `bytes` to `str`.